# Trying to retrofit a button to open up a modal window

Tags: css, html

I've been using the HTML5 UP Photon template https://html5up.net/photon 
I'm trying to retrofit one of the buttons towards the bottom called "Learn More" to open up a modal window with a few paragraphs of text. I've tried to give the button a btnID and link a js function to open it but I can't get it to work. Any help would be appreciated. Here's the html. The preset class references Bootstrap I think.

```
<li><a href="" class="button">Learn More</a></li>
```

Comment: Do you have any component/plugin to work as a modal window?

Comment: Sorry, not really sure what that would be so probably not. Should I?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the template you are using does not provide any modal window component out of the box, so you'd have to find one and plug it in there or write one yourself. Assuming you go for something ready made, you need to do the following:

1. Search for jquery modal window and find one you like.
2. Download it's js and css files and them into your page (or use a CDN)
3. Write some simple jquery to call that modal. It could be as simple as writing `$('a:contains("Learn More")').modal()`. This depends on the modal componet you choose

Let me know in the comments if you want more help